# Check for digits with dashes using regex

Tags: php, regex

If I need a string to match this pattern: "***-**-***","123-12-123","123-1", how would I check the string to make sure it fits that, in PHP?

I want to make sure the string fits any of these patterns:

```
"***-**-***"
"123-12-123" (ONLY NUMERIC WITH -)
"123-1" (ONLY NUMERIC WITH -)
```

Comment: can you add some more example, which are allowed and not allowed. i.e `123-12`, `123-12-12`, `1-12-123` is allowed ?

Comment: You can try [`\d{1,3}-\d{1,2}(?:-\d{1,3})?`](https://regex101.com/r/PQq50A/1/) this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex

```
/\d{3}\-\d(\d\-\d{3}|)/
```

If you need to match only that string, put `^` after the first `/` and `$` before the last `/`

Keep in mind this will match anything that **starts** `ddd-d` as-is

You can see it work here https://3v4l.org/JI5GT

Answer (score 0):

u can find all numbers without regex for example

```
$numbers=sscanf('123-12-123','%d-%d-%d');

print_r($numbers);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 123
)
```

if you want get it with regex you can do with follow code

```
$re = '/\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{3}/m';
$str = '123-12-123';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```